# Showing the location in Windows Phone 7 works in the emulator but not on the real phone

Tags: geolocation, bing-maps, windows-phone

I have code that is used to show a device's location. It works just fine on the emulator and it takes me to the fake location at Microsoft. But it didn't work when I build it into the phone, it showed me the world map. Is this a known bug or I have done something wrong? Here is my code:

```
    private GeoCoordinateWatcher loc = null;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (loc == null)
        {
            loc = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
            loc.StatusChanged += loc_StatusChanged;
        }
        if (loc.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Disabled)
        {
            loc.StatusChanged -= loc_StatusChanged;
            MessageBox.Show("Location services must be enabled on your phone.");
            return;
        }
        loc.Start();
    }

    void loc_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
        {
            Pushpin p = new Pushpin();
            p.Template = this.Resources["pinMyLoc"] as ControlTemplate;
            p.Location = loc.Position.Location;
            mapControl.Items.Add(p);
            map1.SetView(loc.Position.Location, 17.0);
            loc.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is due to my location doesn't support by Bing Map. I couldn't use the Bing Map app installed in my phone neither. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the StatusChanged event, you should use the [GeoCoordinateWatcher.PositionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.positionchanged.aspx) event, in from which you should use the [GeoPositionChangedEventArgs.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808803.aspx) property, to reflect the changed location.